# There have been times that

Tags: grammar

> There have been times that I've felt like I'm not enough.

Or

> There have been times that I felt like I'm not enough.

Or

> Has there been a time that you felt like you're not enough.

Or

> Has there been a time that you've felt like you're not good enough?

Which one of these sounds more correct? Can they both have different meanings? I feel like the first and last ones are the correct ones but I'm not too sure why I see sentences with the second and third structure.

Comment: Do you want "a time" or "times"? Do you want "not enough" or "not good enough"?  Do you want to ask it or say it? Do you want it to be **correct**? or natural?

Comment: The first relative clause is in the present perfect ("I've felt") while the second is in the simple past ("I felt"). Are you aware of when those tenses are used? If so, what is your particular concern with these sentences?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I'm a native English speaker and don't know how your question matters for answering the main question. Can you explain what difference it makes in the 4 sentences that were provided? It would probably answer the question and besides, I'm curious.

Comment: The change in tense has a great impact on which sentence "sounds more correct" and whether the sentences can "have different meanings". ELL's guidelines ask people "to make an effort to research your question before posting it", so I was wondering what you'd found so far.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Hi there. Yes, in general, I know what those tenses mean and how they're used separate from any other sentence. For example, I feel like `Throughout the history, there have been people that have had helpful inventions.` seems correct but `Throughout the history, there have been people that had helpful inventions.` seems awkward. Can they both be true but have different meanings? For example, `I've felt like that before.` is true but we can't say `I felt like that before.` cause we are not talking about a specific time to use simple past, but instead, we use present perfect.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Hi there. My problem is not with either of the ones you said. My problem is with the tense that I should use after `There have been times/There's been a time`...

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Also, we say, `There's always been a person that I've trusted in my life/There have been people that I've trusted in my life (and have regretted it)` but can we also say, `There have always been people that I trusted in my life (and regretted it).`

Comment: @JOUA I'm closing this question for now, because as it stands, it is off-topic because it's asking for proofreading, rather than focusing on a single point of English that you're unsure about. You're asking all sorts of different questions, rather than just one (see Old Brixtonian's comment at the top). Please edit your question (with the small "Edit" button under the question) so that it clearly indicates one single point of English that you'd like help with, rather than being a request for proofreading. Then use the "Reopen" button

Answer (score 0):

"There have been times **where/when** I felt like..." is what you're looking for.

"That", "when" and "where" are all conjunctions, but you cannot necessarily swap them like you did.